# How to remove the html tag and css in c# parameter

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

C# Code:-

```
dynamic RetArgs = new JObject();
RetArgs.abcTest= System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(abcTest, @"<[^>]*(>|$)|&nbsp;|&zwnj;|&raquo;|&laquo;", string.Empty).Trim();
```

showing parameter value:-

```
<div style="box-sizing: border-box; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; font-variant-numeric: inherit; font-variant-east-asian: inherit; font-stretch: inherit; line-height: inherit; font-family: Arimo; vertical-align: baseline; color: rgb(0, 0, 0);">
    Take your medicines as per following directions for 1 month/ 1 महिने के लिए</div>
```

expected result :-

```
Take your medicines as per following directions for 1 month/ 1 महिने के लिए
```

Comment: I think the normal suggestion here is to use something designed for parsing HTML, such as HtmlAgilityPack. Can you advice why/how your current solution isn't working in this case?

Comment: @john actually this my post method this input  parameter pass. and this value insert in ck-editor then generated this values

Comment: @john current solution not working but i am just try it.

Comment: Before you try to write regex to parse html, take a look at this [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: The current solution worked for me when I tested it against the "showing parameter value" example - I got the "expected result" out of `Regex.Replace`. "not working" isn't an accurate description of the problem because "not working" encompasses everything from throwing an exception to returning a blank string to returning your string still with HTML in it, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using [HtmlAgilityPack](https://html-agility-pack.net/) (available on [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack/))

This code:

```
string html = "<div style="box-sizing: border-box; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; font-variant-numeric: inherit; font-variant-east-asian: inherit; font-stretch: inherit; line-height: inherit; font-family: Arimo; vertical-align: baseline; color: rgb(0, 0, 0);">
    Take your medicines as per following directions for 1 month/ 1 महिने के लिए</div>";
var htmlDoc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
htmlDoc.LoadHtml(description);
var fixedHtml = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.InnerText;
```

Produces this output:

```
Take your medicines as per following directions for 1 month/ 1 महिने के लिए
```